# What is a Binaries-based installation on Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, software-rec

can you explain me what a Binaries-based installation is and how does it work?

On linux there is the Package-based installation, the Source-Based Installations and the Binaries-based installation. But I don't know what the Binaries-Based Installation is.

Thanks

Comment: I've never heard the term, but I would assume on the face of it that it means a distribution of Linux in which you usually or always install precompiled binaries, as opposed to something like Gentoo.

Comment: I agree with @Celada -- without more context as to where you heard the term it's impossible to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: ... Sorry, your 'clarification' still really doesn't clarify anything. Again, *where* did you first hear this term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name goes, you only have the binaries, which means you don't have the source code of the program, you have the compiled program.

In windows world, that is usually the way everything works, in Linux since most of the programs are open source you have the code and you can check it for yourself if you want to learn or modify it, or if you are paranoic about someone inserting spyware/backdoor/whatever in that program. You can compile it for yourself when you are happy and you will get YOUR binaries.

Some companies that don't want their software to be open only provide binaries that you can execute to install or run their software/drivers/whatever (for instance video driver modules provided by Nvidia or ATI are binaries)

Since binaries are compiled programs you can have a binary that can be the program itself thus running it you will run the program, or you can have a binary-based installation which means you will have a binary that will make an installation of the program (another binary) in your system.